# What exactly is the vow the Watchers have to take?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-what-if-2021

In episode 8 of *What if... ?* we see

> The Watcher in his dimension, watching the events of the multiverse, when Ultron breaks into the said dimension.

I know that in the comics

> some Watchers have already intervened in some situations, hence breaking the vow.

But I would like to know if there is a similar situation in the comics, where

> Ultron (or someone else) breaking into his dimension and attacking him.

**My question is : If a Watcher is attacked or if the place where he reside is threatened, can he intervene or is it breaking the vow? I want to know for the comics and in the episode 8 situation.**

> Assuming he didn't already break it with the current actions in the episode.

I might actually be misunderstanding the

> dimension The Watcher is in. Being part of the vow somehow.

Sorry for all the spoilers blocks I didn't want to ruin anyone's episode.

**EDIT :** I rephrased my question. I tried to be vague not to spoil while still trying to convey my point but I guess I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: *"Watchy-watchy, no touchy-touchy"*

Comment: In comics, there is not some external “Watcher Dimension” outside the MCU’s boundary; the main Watcher from the comics’ and the frequent narrator of the various comic What If series, Uatu the Watcher, simply had a base on the moon from which he watched earthly events. FWIW, as a plot point, the Dreaming Celestial scanned Uatu and determined he broke the “non-interference pact” more than 400 times, which was really just a symbol of how much Uatu cares for Earth and Earth’s heroes which are the constant source for his rule-breaking.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - so Uatu takes it about as seriously as The Prime Directive...in that, only when it's a convenient to not do he doesn't want to do anyway

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "Would it be breaking the vow if The Watcher did something?" He does a fair few things in the episode itself, and it's intimated he's planning to do some more. Are you asking if this breaks the vow he took, in the show? Or are you asking if he takes a similar vow in the comics, and what constitutes a breach of that vow?

Comment: In the comics, the Watchers are not allowed to interfere, but they can defend themself. There are several instances of people entering the Uatu's home uninvited and getting thrown out. A short story also shows a space pirate mocking a Watcher for their inability to help and tells him all about his plans to sack the planet nearby, not knowing that the planet was the Watcher's original home planet. It did not end well for the pirate.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thanks, like I said in my edit after your comment "I tried to be vague not to spoil while still trying to convey my point but I guess I wasn't clear enough.", I hope the new question is clearer, I asked for a reopen.

Comment: @PhilippeB. To make the question even clearer, it would help if you added if you are asking about MCU only, or if you include other media, like comics. The rules might not be the same in different marvel universes.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Yes I realized after and just saw your comment thanks, I edited again :)

Comment: Cool. I feel like it might be two separate questions. In the comics, there's years of _What If...?_ and Watcher stuff. In the MCU, we pretty much just have this episode —  I think it's the first time he mentioned taking a vow, so we have no idea what the scope of it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comics, Uatu and his clan of Watchers are bound by a vow taken by the head of their clan, Uatu's father, Ikor.

<sub><sup>**[Tales of Suspense #54](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_of_Suspense_Vol_1_54)**</sup></sub>
[image]

In short, Watchers aren't forbidden to defend themselves but they are forbidden to interfere with the 'destinies' of other races.

<sub><sup>[**Tales of Suspense #57**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_of_Suspense_Vol_1_57)</sup></sub>
[image]

Purely for the record, Uatu has broken this vow so many times in the comics that it's more like a vague guideline to him.

Comment: Thanks ! As a side note I believe that I saw at some point (in the comics I thing) a Watcher saying that if he did interfere he would lose his power or be punished in some sort, according to your last phrase this is me misremembering right ?

Comment: @PhilippeB - Uatu's backstory had changed a fair bit over the years and reboots. It wouldn't surprise me if they changed his raison d'etre a few times as well

Comment: @PhillipeB. - on reflection that would probably be a good one to ask as a story identification question, e.g. "*In which comic serial was Uatu told that if he broke his Watchers' vow, that he would lose his powers or be punished"*

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I might edit the question to match the format, I'm not used to this SE yet ! But wouldn't that be a bad question as a story identification if there was no answer ? Since I have no clue if the event you're mentioning happened or not.

Comment: @PhillipeB. - If you have a recollection of it, it's worth asking, I'd say. I'll leave it to your good judgement though

Comment: Actually I didn't read any comics, I only go on the wiki or on this SE looking for facts from comics when I need. So I don't even have a recollection of it since I only know the MCU ! But if you can assure me there is such an event I will consider changing my question (or asking a new one since the subject is interresting).